# Filter group if one entry has specific value

Tags: mysql

I have a table of tasks:

```
task_id | done_by_user_id
-------------------------
1       | 1
1       | 2
2       | 1
2       | 3
3       | 3
4       | 1
```

The table contains data which task has be solved by which user, whereas each task can be solved by more than one user. I already have a query that groups the tasks and counts how many users have worked on each task: `SELECT task_id, COUNT(*) FROM tasks GROUP BY task_id`

Next, I want to filter all groups by user: When one task was solved by one user, I want that task to be removed from my results. What I first tried was `SELECT task_id, COUNT(*) FROM tasks WHERE done_by_user_id != ? GROUP BY task_id` but that only decreases the count but does not filter the whole group.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT task_id, COUNT(*) 
FROM tasks 
GROUP BY task_id
HAVING NOT SUM(done_by_user_id = ?)
```

`SUM(done_by_user_id = ?)` calculates the amount of rows for current `task_id` and provided user.

`NOT` allows to return only those rows where this SUM is zero.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

```
SELECT t.task_id, COUNT(*)
FROM tasks AS t
LEFT OUTER JOIN tasks AS u
 ON t.task_id=u.task_id AND u.done_by_user_id=?
WHERE u.task_id IS NULL
GROUP BY t.task_id;
```

Explanation: try to match each row `t` to another row `u` referencing the same task and the specific user. If no match exists, then the outer join will treat the columns of `u` as NULL. You want those cases, so where `u.*` is NULL, those are the groups you want to keep.